# command + tab or clicking on any app in dock opens all windows of that application

Tags: macos, mojave

command  + tab or clicking on any app in dock opens all windows of that application (except those which are minimised)

I started experiencing this recently, around 2 weeks back

Earlier, if I pressed command + tab click on any app icon in the doc, it would only open the latest active window of that application. But now, it opens all the windows of that app and bring all windows to front.

Is this behaviour expected?

If I'm working with two application Chrome and Finder and I've 5 finder windows opened. It's very frustrating if I Command + Tab and want to go to the latest finder window as it opens all windows and not just the latest one

Answer (score 1):

cmd-Tab in macOS always works like this. It switches apps instead of windows, and all non-minimized windows of the app in current desktop will popup.

alt-Tab in MS Windows switches windows.

Personally I like the behavior of MS Windows. If you want this behavior, you might check something like HyperSwitch.

Comment: I had a different experience. cmd-Tab switches app but only the latest/recent non-minimized window of the app in the current desktop pops us. And then we can use Cmd-` to switch to any other window of the app if we want

The above behaviour is what I had been experiencing since I bough Mac (recently around 2 months back). Only from past 2 weeks, all the non-minimized windows of the apps are popping up which seems to be a bug (I'm not sure fully)

Comment: I checked at an apple store and yes, it always works like this. Perhaps what I remember was wrong :)